# setting different colors for 25 lines in my line chrt

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to give a different color for each line in my plot, my plot has 25 lines and I want the color to be distinctive to each other as much as possible
I tried the legend function but it is cycling the colors after 10 iterations
he is the part of my code that is related to the plotting

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
for cluster_index in [0,1,2]:

    plt.subplot(3,1,cluster_index + 1)

    for index, row in data_consumption2.iterrows():
        if row.iloc[-1] == cluster_index:
            plt.plot(row.iloc[1:-1] ,marker='x', alpha=1)

        plt.legend(loc="best")

    plt.plot(kmeans.cluster_centers_[cluster_index], color='k' ,marker='o', alpha=1)

    plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
    plt.ylabel('Electricity Consumption')
    plt.title(f'Cluster {cluster_index}', fontsize=20)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I would appreciate any help for this issue.

Comment: It looks like you are actually plotting 8 lines for each of three clusters. Perhaps you want to consider re-using 8 colors, and make the clusters distinct another way.  You can use subplots, so you have three plots with the same axis, or you can plot them with an offset, or you can change the line styles/widths for each cluster.

Comment: but the numbers of lines in my cluster are not equal, first cluster has 20, the second 2 and the third 2

Answer (score 2):

Python Matplotlib has 8 built in colors. SO if you don't specify they take in consideration these built-in colors are rotated.
However matplotlib allows coder to specify in the format, 'c' followed  by a number.
Like, c0: the first color in the cycle ; c1: second color in the cycle;
So, if you write,

```
color='0.75'
```

this will give you an in between shade.

Also it pretty much follows HTML pattern, so you can actually give colors as hexadecimal or rgb format.

The RGB format is written as,

```
color='rgb(255, 0, 0)'
```

It is the color code for red. In rgb, the first color is for red, second one is for green and third one is for blue, all ranging from 0 to 255.
so, rgb(0,0,0) is black and rgb(255,255,255) is white.

Also you can use Hexa code like,

```
color='#ff6347'
```

is also red.

Values for colors is found on w3 schools.
Hope this works.

Comment: it works in terms of the logic of assigning a color but it didn`t help in my code, thanks a lot I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to do that is using HSV instead of RGB. You just need to change H to have a significant change.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)

for i in range(1,26):
  hsv = ((1/25)*i,.8,.8)
  plt.plot(x*i, color = colors.hsv_to_rgb(hsv))

plt.show()
```

That outputs

[image]

You can also use iteration to change *saturation* and *value* to get more constrast between the plots.

Comment: thanks for your answer, what if the main for loop has an enormous range and not 1-26?

Comment: I mean the counter that u r using in your code is from 1-26 but mine is huge and I cant add one more loop to my code!

Comment: It is just an example. As you said in your question you do 25 plots, so in somewhere in your code you can do something like i did to iterate over the colors. Just be careful, bigger the range that you use, less constrast you will have between plots.

Comment: I mean in my example, with what will I replace the i to generate different hsv?
I tried to declare a new variable but it gave me an error

Comment: Declare a new variable "i" starting equals 1. Then change your plots to plt.plot(...., color = colors.hsv_to_rgb( ((1/25)*i),.8,.8 )) and under declares "i += 1", it will solve your problem

Comment: that works, thank u!
last question plz, how can I change the saturation to get more contrast between the plots?

Comment: You can use the fact that "i" will be even or odd each time. So your hsv can be ((1/25)*i), 0.2 + (i%2)/2 ,.8 ). Im not sure what is the effect of this, you will need to try values that improve your image.